# Sort IP's associated to a string in a txt file in linux

Tags: linux, sort, numeric-data

Could someone help me sorting numerically the IP's from a .txt file containing string with an IP associated to it.

Content in txt:

```
string_A=10.a.y.155
string_B=10.a.y.212
string_C=10.a.y.104
string_D=10.a.y.10
string_E=10.a.y.198
string_U=10.b.x.155
string_V=10.b.x.212
string_X=10.b.x.104
string_Y=10.b.x.10
string_Z=10.b.x.198
```

The output I want:

```
10.a.x._ series in sorted way.

string_D=10.a.y.10
string_C=10.a.y.104
string_A=10.a.y.155
string_E=10.a.y.198
string_B=10.a.y.212
```

---

I am not sure if I could post the original values due to our companies data policy. So, these dummy values instead.

Comment: this is not public IPs and you could post it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `-V` ("version sort"), implemented by most `sort`:

```
$ sort -t '=' -k2 -V file
string_D=10.a.y.10
string_C=10.a.y.104
string_A=10.a.y.155
string_E=10.a.y.198
string_B=10.a.y.212
string_Y=10.b.x.10
string_X=10.b.x.104
string_U=10.b.x.155
string_Z=10.b.x.198
string_V=10.b.x.212
```

If `a=15` and `b=140`:

```
$ sort -t '=' -k2 -V file
string_D=10.15.y.10
string_C=10.15.y.104
string_A=10.15.y.155
string_E=10.15.y.198
string_B=10.15.y.212
string_Y=10.140.x.10
string_X=10.140.x.104
string_U=10.140.x.155
string_Z=10.140.x.198
string_V=10.140.x.212
```

The `-k2` with `-t '='` makes `sort` consider the data after the `=` as the sort key.

Comment: You could add an input line like `string_F=10.a.y.5` to highlight the numerical ordering of version sort.

Answer (score 1):

With `sort` command:

```
sort -t'=' -k2 file
```

- `-t'='` - `=` sign as field separator
- `-k2` - sorting by the 2nd field

The output:

```
string_D=10.a.y.10
string_C=10.a.y.104
string_A=10.a.y.155
string_E=10.a.y.198
string_B=10.a.y.212
string_Y=10.b.x.10
string_X=10.b.x.104
string_U=10.b.x.155
string_Z=10.b.x.198
string_V=10.b.x.212
```

Comment: if in array will addresses: 10.15.210.10 and 10.140.22.212, you command return 10.140.22.212 first

Comment: @EgorVasilyev, and will return correctly, cause `10.15.210` and `10.140.22` are in different groups. From the question: *10.a.x._ series in sorted way.*

Comment: This would misplace lines where the numerical ordering differs from the lexical, such as e.g. `string_F=10.a.y.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sort -t. -nk1,1 -nk2,2 -nk3,3 -nk4,4 file
```

`-n` - sorting numerically

You need to sort by **each of four field**.